# Is it possible to merge two apps on the App Store into a single app?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

Here's the situation: I created an app and released it, only to discover a friend of mine had actually created a similar app. We decided to combine our efforts and make a single app going forward, using his app's name (and my code).

Now granted my app was *just* released so there's practically nobody using it, but even so I'd like to not just abandon those people that may be using it. I'd love it if there were some way to merge the apps such that users of my app were notified of an updated version that actually downloads the other app's bundleid (but which will have the same codebase as the previous version of mine).

Is there any support for this scenario on the App Store?

***Failing that***, I would at the very least like to transfer purchases of the old app into purchases of the new app.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about app store policy,This might be on topic for AskDifferent but I suspect the answer is no

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think there is any way to do what you describe. Apple treats apps as completely separate, and does not allow you to transfer one to another.